# Server-side DOM storage with Node

Tags: node.js, dom, datastore

Have you seen anyone using a server-side DOM as a datastore, via jsdom or cheerio in node, maybe with a library to query the DOM using conventions like an ActiveRecord-style API?

Seems obvious, albeit extremely slow with significant amount of data, but I can't find a reference to anyone doing this.

Comment: Can you say precisely what you mean by "Node.js' DOM"? There's no such thing built into node core. There's a jsdom npm module and a cheerio npm module, but I'm not clear on what you are asking about.

Comment: @PeterLyons, yes, sorry, I do mean with jsdom or cheerio.

Answer (score 0):

No I have seen no such thing. Frankly, I can't think why anyone would do that. My guess is you think the documents created with jsdom/cheerio are persisted to disk. That's not the case. They are in-memory only. They are a data structure, but not a data store.

You can use basic javascript data structures (arrays & objects) as in-memory data stores. There is also an in-memory data store made to be interoperable with mongodb. Not sure what tree you are barking up with ActiveRecord, but ActiveRecord pairs with a relational data store, not a DOM, which is a tree structure.

https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb

https://npmjs.org/package/node-memory-cache

https://npmjs.org/package/memcouch